# How to display all methods that are called within a specific method in Eclipse Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a method

```
public String doStuff(){    
  new A().callMethodA();
  B b = new B();
  b.callMethodB();
  return "stuff";
}
```

How can I display that in the method `doStuff()` two other methods `callMethodA()` and `callMethodB()` are called?

Open Call Hierarchy can dispay where `doStuff` is called, but I would like to see all the other methods that are called within `doStuff`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The  view "Call Hierarchy" has some actions in the view specific tool bar named

- [image] "Show Caller Hierarchy": Show all callers in the search scope of the selected member.
- [image] "Show Callee Hierarchy": Show all members which are called by the currently selected member.

[Call Hierarchy View](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fref-call-hierarchy.htm)

This you should toogle

Comment: big thx! did not see the icon in the right upper corner. They should have something similar to ctrl+alt+H